# Why simply connected solvable analytic groups have no nontrivial compact subgroups?

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, solvable-groups

Why do simply connected solvable analytic groups have no nontrivial compact subgroups? I'll appreciate any help on this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a $n$-dimensional connected Lie group $G$ the maximal compact subgroup is trivial if and only if $G$ is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$. But if $G$ is simply connected and solvable, then it is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$. For references see [here](https://books.google.at/books?id=l8nJCNiIQAAC&pg=PA52&lpg=PA52&dq=compact+subgroups+of+simply-connected+solvable+Lie+group&source=bl&ots=pI7-0qlVay&sig=fosOtLUbsLbw-Au9ZF1hR7LsUSs&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwidt8LTwtPJAhWFbRQKHSc9B54Q6AEILzAC#v=onepage&q=compact%20subgroups%20of%20simply-connected%20solvable%20Lie%20group&f=false).

Comment: Ah, okay. ${}{}$

Comment: Thanks, Dietrich. Your suggestion was useful; I was able to fill in the details!

Comment: You are welcome. Actually, there is Iwasawa's theorem saying that $G$ is homeomorphic to $C\times \mathbb{R}^k$ for some $k$ and maximal compact subgroup $C$ of $G$. So "simply-connected solvable" says that $C=1$ is trivial.